# If a diamond weighing $4$kg breaks into $2$ pieces, its total value decreases by $37.5$%. What is the weight of the two pieces?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

The value of a diamond is directly proportional to square of its weight. If a diamond weighing $4$kg breaks into $2$ pieces, its total value decreases by $37.5$%. What is the weight of the two pieces?

My teacher solved it by taking one piece weight as $x$ and the other piece weight as $4-x$. Then the total value of the two pieces were
$T= kx^2+k(4-x)^2$.

Then I didn't understand the next step:

$$\frac{kx^2+k(4-x)^2}{k(4)^2}=\frac58$$

I didn't understand the above quadratic equation. Help me out

Comment: Math.SE is not a chat site, but a question-and-answer site whose posts are intended to be useful to others in the future. Please give your questions (including [How to solve this tricky question? I didn't understand this one at all.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067185) and [How to solve this one? This is tricky](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067144)) descriptive titles that will help others. Doing so will also help _you_ figure out what you're really asking, which is probably not details of specific test problems, but some underlying mathematical skill. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of the two pieces is before breaking them is $$V_1 = k\cdot 4^2 .$$ Their value after breaking them is $$V_2= kx^2+k(4-x)^2.$$

You know that $V_2$ is $37.5\%$ (or $\frac38$) less than $V_1$, in other words,

$$V_2 = V_1 - \frac38 V_1 = \frac 58 V_1.$$

In other words, $$\frac{V_2}{V_1} = \frac58.$$

Answer (score 0):

The second equation if the ratio of the value of the 2 pieces to the value of the whole. It is decreased by 37.5% so the ratio must be (100-37.5)/100=5/8

Answer (score 0):

The value of the diamond **before it broke** is proportional to the square of the weight, that is, $4$ kg. Hence, we can take the value as: $T_1=k(4)^2$.

---

Now, **after it broke**, it split into two pieces weighing $x$ and $4-x$ kg. Hence, we can calculate the total value as $T_2 = kx^2 + k(4-x)^2$.

---

Now, we have $$T_2 = \frac{5}{8}T_1 $$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{kx^2 + k(4-x)^2}{k(4)^2} =\frac{5}{8}$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint

The initial value is

$$V_0=k4^2$$

after breaking it, the new value is

$$kx^2+k(4-x)^2=V_0-\frac{V_0}{100}.37.7$$

$$\implies kx^2+k(4-x)^2=k4^2\frac{62.3}{100}.$$

Now you solve the quadratic for $x$.